# How to convert a function into neural network layer

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, feature-selection

```
import numpy as np
import math


def fs(X, Y, w, param):
    eta = 0.2
    lamb = 0.01

    for x, y in zip(X, Y):  
        y = -1 if y == 0 else 1

        f = np.dot(w, x)  

        if y * f <= 1: 
            w = w + eta * y * x
            w = w * min(1, 1/(math.sqrt(lamb) * np.linalg.norm(w)))
            w = trun(w, param['num_features'])

    return w, param


def trun(w, num_features):
    if len(w.nonzero()[0]) > num_features:
        w_sort_idx = np.argsort(abs(w))[-num_features:]
        zero_indices = [x for x in range(len(w)) if x not in w_sort_idx]
        w[zero_indices] = 0
    return w
```

I tried this feature selection method to convert it into a neural network for classification. But I am not able to convert this. please help me to sort this out.